# Change the state of a button that is repeated in multiple places in the page, but only the button that is clicked, and not the rest

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I have a cluster of buttons that behave like a toggle. I have this "button group" repeated in various rows inside of a table. I want the user to be able to click on button inside this "button group" and triggered an "active state" (colors it differently) but only of that specific "button group", inside of that specific row

Any clues of how to achieve this? plz help

I've already tried an if statement in jquery using class but then it presents the problem of removing the "btn-active" class from other buttons in order to have only one button with the "btn-active" inside that group in particular.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.buttongroup-toggle').click(function(a) {
    if ($(this).hasClass(".btn-active")) {
      $(this).addClass(".btn-active");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass(".btn-active");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.btn-group button {
  background-color: $color-blue-dark;
  border: none;
  /* arch-dark blue border */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px;
  /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left;
  /* Float the buttons side by side */
  outline: none;
  &.btn-active {
    background-color: $color-arch-blue;
    border-color: $color-arch-blue;
  }
}


/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */

.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none;
  /* Prevent double borders */
}

.btn-group button:first-child {
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}

.btn-group button:last-child {
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
}


/* Add a background color on hover */

.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: lighten($color-blue-dark, 5%);
  border-color: lighten($color-blue-dark, 5%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="buttongroup-toggle btn-active">No Change</button>

  <button class="buttongroup-toggle">Default Cured</button>

  <button class="buttongroup-toggle">Remove Bankruptcy</button>
</div>
```

I want that, whatever button I click, the "btn-active" class be added, and that same class be removed from the rest of the buttons that are inside of that "button-group", but only in that button-group specifically,  so that this behavior can be repeated in different "button-groups" repeated across the page.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve but first thing one can see is your if statement doesn't make any sense because it does the same action no matter the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.buttongroup-toggle').click(function(a) {
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("btn-active");
      $(this).addClass("btn-active");        
   });
});
```

Comment: ahh it works partially! although what if I repeat the same btn-group in different places in my page? like...how do I keep the "btn-active" class in the first btn-group to remain like that if i click another button in another btn-group that is in a different place in the code?

Comment: just edited my post for the specific group code too ;)

Comment: ahh it works!! the $(this).parent().children().removeClass("btn-active"); was the charm!! super thanks!! n_n

Comment: I found out that using the siblings method is even better and more appropriate for your case : $(this).siblings().removeClass("btn-active");